# Errors not being logged to txt file

Tags: django

Hi have the following code in my setting.py file.

Upon a 500 error, an email gets sent out with the details of the error, an error.txt file gets created in the directory noted below, but the txt file is empty. No errors are being written to this txt file. Any thoughts?

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
         'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/jasonhoward/webapps/myproject/jason/errors.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },

        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your 'django.request' logger, add 'file', like this:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
         'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/jasonhoward/webapps/myproject/jason/errors.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins','file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },

        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },

    }
}
```

This error is a request error.